# MySQL Update null column values incrementally in time order

Tags: php, mysql

There is a table with hundreds of entries and six columns. One of those columns, the 'transaction' column, has been filling up with null values, we now need that column to have unique values, existing entries are unique.

There is a 'time' datetime column, ideally the 'transaction' column would be updated incrementally with integers starting from 1 in 'time' order.

This seems simple but after several times dropping and restoring a live database it now seems less simple and a little help would be greatly appreciated.

[SQL Fiddle - Sample of live database](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71f19d/3/0)

**Final solution** many thanks to Juan Carlos Oropeza for the solution and being patient with me.

```
UPDATE `my_table` t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT t.*, 
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS `rank`
        FROM `my_table` t, 
             (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
        ORDER BY time
       ) t2
ON t1.`id` = t2.`id`
SET t1.`transaction` = t2.`rank` where t1.`transaction` is null
```

Comment: Your table has primary key? Show us dbschema.

Comment: The plan was to make the 'transaction' column the primary key as it will be unique. I can add an ID column as primary key to do this task then drop it afterwards. It does not seem useful to have another ID column as it will never be used.

Comment: That is why you should put that info on the question on first place. Now please put your create table and maybe I can fix my query.

Comment: I've now added a sample of the live database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dd389/1)**

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT t.*, 
                   @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS `rank`
            FROM Table1 t, 
                 (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
            // ORDER BY time   use your datetime field
           ) t2
    ON t1.`ID` = t2.`ID`    // You need a PK field
SET t1.`value` = t2.`rank`  // Update your sequence field
```

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ID` int, `value` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ID`, `value`)
VALUES
    (10, NULL),
    (20, NULL),
    (30, NULL)
;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | value |
|----|-------|
| 10 |     1 |
| 20 |     2 |
| 30 |     3 |
```

EDIT:

or just create a new ID field to be PK

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75ea01/1)

```
alter table `wp_user_txs` add column `id` int(10) unsigned primary KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Only about a third of the values are NULL, the rest already have values that must not be overridden, that's what I meant by "existing entries are unique".

Comment: Again, put that info in the question. Very frustrating you keep adding restriction after I already answer your problem :(  Put db schema, sample data and desire output to remove any ambiguity from your question. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Check my edit, and let me know if that is enough. Otherwise one you have the `auto_increment` column you can use my first query to fill the `transaction` column. just add `where transaction is null`